# Divs alinhadas com Height diferentes

Tags: css, materialize

Eu preciso fazer esse efeito de as divs estarem com tamanhos diferentes, mas sempre 'encaixadas', mas não estou conseguindo deixar dessa forma. Estou utilizando o Materialize, tem algum 'truque' pra isso?

Não sei se facilita, mas deixei aqui uma estrutura um pouco parecida com as divs que eu tenho https://jsfiddle.net/5gy7apL4/[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
.col {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 16px;
}

.maior {
  height: 250px;
}

.menor {
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="col s3 maior"></div>
   <div class="col s3 menor"></div>
   <div class="col s3 maior"></div>
   <div class="col s3 maior"></div>
   <div class="col s3 menor"></div>
   <div class="col s3 maior"></div>
   <div class="col s3 maior"></div>
   <div class="col s3 menor"></div>
   <div class="col s3 maior"></div>
</div>
```